# Build gcc on linux script

Tags: bash, unix, gcc, build

Good day, i write script for building gcc on linux, my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

export INSTALLATION_GCC=/opt

cd $INSTALLATION_GCC

tar xjvf gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2

export srcdir="$INSTALLATION_GCC/gcc-4.7.0"

export objdir="$INSTALLATION_GCC/gcc-bin"

export insdir="$INSTALLATION_GCC/usr/local"

mkdir -p $srcdir

mkdir -p $objdir

mkdir -p $insdir

cd $objdir

$srcdir/configure --prefix=$insdir

make bootstrap
```

make install

but when i run this script i get errors:

```
No such file or directoryopt
tar (child): gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2\r: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
/configure: No such file or directory
'.  Stop. No rule to make target `bootstrap
'.  Stop. No rule to make target `install
```

Why cd not work successful, if i execute my script (if i input this command in interactive mode all ok)?After building and installing gcc why my version of gcc not changing, how can i replace old version gcc properly?

Comment: There is something strange here, the error message `No such file or directoryopt` is missing a space and a `/`.  It looks to me like your code did not generate this error message, are you sure that `$INSTALLATION_GCC` is `/opt` with the leading `/`?  It almost appears that the first character of `$INSTALLATION_GCC` is a backspace.

Comment: to debug a bash-script, add `-x` after the shebang, i.e. `#!/bin/bash -x` or use ´set -x´. You scrips is probably lacking some quotes...

Comment: May I ask why you need to build the gcc by yourself? What are you trying to achieve? I have a feeling you are heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: I interesting how can i build gcc from sources,me needed new version gcc because i use new c++ futures.How can i use -x option to debug my script please discuss more details.

Comment: Simplest way to debug is to use `bash -x script-name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my comment about a backspace being part of the directory name is relevant:

"There is something strange here, the error message No such file or directoryopt is missing a space and a /. It looks to me like your code did not generate this error message, are you sure that $INSTALLATION_GCC is /opt with the leading /? It almost appears that the first character of $INSTALLATION_GCC is a backspace."

I also spied `gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2\r` in one of the error messages.  A `\r` would give these effects.  The most common unwanted source of `\r` (carriage-return) is Windows.  Are you using something like Notepad on Windows to edit your scripts?  If Windows is involved, convert your script using `dos2unix`.

Comment: You right, i write this script on windows platform (in Windows all line ends with /r) it is a main mistake, the main rule is: if you write something platform depending text you must write this code on this platform.